# Using A Cell To Reference The Name Of Sheet In A Formula In Excel

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have the same problem as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319026/using-a-cell-to-reference-the-name-of-sheet-in-a-formula-for-google-sheets).

The solution provided also works in excel, but for an empty cell in the referenced sheet it prints 0 rather than leaving it empty. Is there a better way to do this where an empty cell would stay empty after referenced?

Comment: What if you include `&"!"` in your query?

Comment: Where would I add that? Let's say I have INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A1")

Comment: `INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A1"&"!")`

Comment: It gave me a "#Ref!" error

Comment: `IF(ISBLANK(Referenced Cell),"", your formula)`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I used ```=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!A2")),"", INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!A2"))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding &"" to the end of your formula; for example:
='Sales Report - WB 10.06'!B3&""

Comment: Thanks, I tried ```=INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!A2")&""``` and it worked.