# Is it possible to reference a cell value as a sheetname in part of a formula in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

In this formula:
countifs('Student A'!$A:$A, $A8, 'Student A'!$B:$B,">="&H$6,'Student A'!$B:$B,"<="&EOMONTH(H$6,0), 'Student A'!$C:$C, "Attended*")

Is it possible to have "Student A" as a cell, and this formula refers to it but keep the formula the same?  Because I don't want to have to keep change the formula for every student name, if I can have a student name column, and this formula can use that to refer to that student's sheet.

I tried some of the solutions I found on the web using indirect ([Using A Cell To Reference The Name Of Sheet In A Formula For Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319026/using-a-cell-to-reference-the-name-of-sheet-in-a-formula-for-google-sheets)), but it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Yes. Possible. Use `INDIRECT()` function then.

Answer (score 1):

INDIRECT is the way, no other option. Possibly the concatenation of text was the issue

```
=countifs(INDIRECT(A1&"!$A:$A"), $A8,
INDIRECT(A1&"!$B:$B"),">="&H$6,'
INDIRECT(A1&"!$B:$B"),"<="&EOMONTH(H$6,0), 
INDIRECT(A1&"!$C:$C"), "Attended*")
```